# How to give mic input as stdin to C program

Tags: c, audio, raw

I currently have written a code which takes in a raw file as input and does some audio processing and writes it to another different raw file.

The way I am currently inputting is

```
.\my_code_binary < input.raw > output.raw
```

as you can see, I am making the input.raw as stdin and output.raw as stdout for the execution my program.

```
fread(tmp, sizeof(short), channels * size_of_frame, stdin); // the way I am using the input.raw
fwrite(tmp, sizeof(short), channels * FRAME_SIZE, stdout); // the way I am using the output.raw
```

Now I want to make my program run real-time, as in, take my mic input as stdin and mic output as stdout. Any resources or code snippets will help me out, I am a beginner at audio processing in C.

EDIT : I am using a Raspberry Pi 4

Comment: Sounds more like an OS issue than a C programming issue. Do you know the devices you're trying to read/write ?

Comment: it's an RPi 4, sorry I missed that out

Comment: Did you try to redirect the devices instead of files? Something like `./my_code_binary < /dev/mic > /dev/audio` (I have no Raspi at hand, the names are most probably wrong)?

Comment: What creates `input.raw`?

Comment: input.raw is just a raw file recording which I just loaded onto my RPi through SSH.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the shell redirection you could try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    FILE *infile, *outfile;
    int c;

    infile = fopen("myinfile", "r");
    outfile = fopen("myoutfile", "w");

    while((c = getc(infile)) != EOF) {
        c = c * 2;  // do something
        putc(c,outfile);
    }

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
}
```

However, this is not real-time as it requires, that the file `myinfile` already exists. As Linux handles all devices as files, You could try to use the device file associated with your microphone as `myinfile`, e.g.`/dev/mymicrophone`.

You may also consider using the more basic Low-Level-I/O functions, that use filedescriptors instead of the `struct FILE`.